# Store JSON from Restful Web Service in List

Tags: java, json, rest

I created a RESTful Java client and i am trying to store the JSON from the server to a List, but can't seem to do it. Tried to use the findAll() method, but no luck so far. How else can i do this? My code is as follows:

Note: All references to XML have been removed. Everything is JSON.

SalaryStructureClient.java

```
package Consumer;

import javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;

public class SalaryStructureClient {
    private WebTarget webTarget;
    private Client client;
    private static final String BASE_URI = "http://swiftworld.com/mass/web";

    public SalaryStructureClient() {
        client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
        webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("salarystructure");
    }

    public void remove(String id) throws ClientErrorException {
        webTarget.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("{0}", new Object[]{id})).request().delete();
    }
```

Control.java

```
public String getCount() {
        count = getClient().countREST();
        return count;
    }

    public List<SalaryStructure> getList() {
        list = getClient().findAll(List.class); //Don't really know what to do here...
        return list;
    }



    public void saveToDB(){
        JsonObject json = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("structureLongName", structure.getStructureLongName())
                .add("structureShortName", structure.getStructureShortName())
                .build();

        getClient().create(json);
        structure = new SalaryStructure();
    }
```

All the other methods are working perfectly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research, finally got it working using the following method:

```
public List<SalaryStructure> getList() {
        list = client1.target("http://swiftworld.com/mass/web")
                .path("salarystructure")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(new GenericType<List<SalaryStructure>>() {});
        return list;
    }
```